# Trigger events on elements attached with Leaflet DomEvent utility

Tags: javascript, leaflet

We use a few Leaflet plugins that internally create some DOM elements (buttons, textboxes, checkboxes, etc) using *L.DomUtil*. The events to them were attached using *L.DomEvent*.

How to correctly trigger them?

I've tried plain JS/jQuery but it doesn't work. I see that it attaches events by creating new function properties. So, what worked for me is:

```
var leafletKeypressEvts = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(domElem).filter(function (p) {
    return p.indexOf('_leaflet_keypress') === 0;
});
leafletKeypressEvts.forEach(function(e) { domElem[e]({keyCode: 13}); });
```

What is the Leaflet way doing this?

UPDATE

It also works like this:

```
var e = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {ctrlKey: false, which: 13, keyCode: 13, returnValue: true, bubbles: true, cancelable: true,keyIdentifier: "Enter"});
Object.defineProperty(e, 'keyCode', {get:function(){return this.keyCodeVal;}}); 
e.keyCodeVal = 13;
domElem.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Don't understand why jquery doesn't work.

Comment: You mean trigger them manually? How about `fireEvent` ? http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events-fireevent

Comment: Yes, manually. There is no such function for the button

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong? For example, I see in the source of the plugin that the guys creating a simple *<input type=text>* and attaching handler with `L.DomEvent.addListener(this._elem, 'keypress', this._keyPressed, this);`. How would you do it?

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to understand your question more. Did you remove the jQuery example code block you had before?

Comment: No, I tried to call it with `$(domElem).trigger('keypress')`. but it didn't help

Comment: any chance of you posting a demo page somewhere so we can see the entire situation?